# Range filtering on excel and count rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need your help about an excel range filtering, it's about a school project.
I have an excel file with 20k rows and a column with number range from 0 to 350k and I need somehow to filter them every 1k (0-999,1000-1999 etc) and to count how many rows/records have every team.

I am thinking about macros or VBA script but i don't even know the starting point, i hope someone can help me from where to start.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not use a `COUNTIFS` formula like `=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=0",A:A,"<=999")`. Your question is pretty unclear to give a really precise answer. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Because if the range is between 0 and 350k, i must run 350 COUNTIFS by hand for every 1k range.

Comment: Why by hand the formula will update whenever the values in column A change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No VBA needed:

If your values are in column A, just enter `0` and `9999` like in columns D/E. The rest of the numbers can be done with `=D2+1000` and `=E2+1000` and pulled down until 350k.

The counting can be done with `=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D:D,A:A,"<="&E:E)` in column F and pulled down.

[image]

Comment: awesome, I believe the most simple and quick implementation, many thanks!

Comment: ... keeping it simple should (always) be a leading design principle, c.f. [KISS principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365 we can do this in one formula and the results will spill:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2,3},SEQUENCE(351,,0,1000),SEQUENCE(351,,999,1000),FREQUENCY(A:A,SEQUENCE(350,,999,1000)))
```

Frequency is designed to take the number and the array of buckets and return the count.

[image]

With LET we can move the variables to the front:

```
=LET(
    rng,     A:A,
    nmbckts, 351,
    gp,      1000,
    CHOOSE({1,2,3},
         SEQUENCE(nmbckts,,0,gp),
         SEQUENCE(nmbckts,,gp-1,gp),
         FREQUENCY(rng,SEQUENCE(nmbckts-1,,gp-1,gp))))
```